# FTP демон при подключении выдаёт ошибку "500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()"

Tags: ubuntu, vsftpd, ftp-сервер

возникла проблема с vsftpd на ubuntu 18.04. Не так уж и давно использовал его и он стабильно работал а тут он при подключении выдаёт ошибку "500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()" и именно при подключение а не авторизации.

Лог - пустой.
Загружается нормально.

Comment: При подключении к чистой vsftpd (Без настройке) такая же ошибка

Comment: Может переустановить ubuntu в 25 раз? Если что в прошлые разы переустановки он работа, а переустановка было по другой причине

Answer (score 0):

можно обойти проверку, поставив флаг:

```
echo 'allow_writeable_chroot=YES' >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

и перезапустить службу

```
systemctl restart vsftpd
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже это пробовал